# How to add comma between numbers in a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I'm wondering is there anyway to add a comma between numbers.

For example: `[0.44346713 0.70174108 0.46043481 0.82511308 0.71445151]`
to `[0.44346713, 0.70174108, 0.46043481, 0.82511308, 0.71445151]`  in python

Thus, i can call each number in an array(e.g., list[0], list[2]...)

Comment: Is that a string? It's not a valid list.

Comment: How do you get this value and what type is it ?

Comment: okay, wait a second, let me add a minimum example

Comment: You list is a `numpy` array. `lst[0]` will work on it.

Comment: If it is numpy.array, you can use .tolist() method.

Comment: yes, Gal moran answered it.

Comment: Why do you think this conversion is necessary? A numpy array can already be indexed, much more flexible than a list.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Then you can tell us, not everyone knows it ....

Comment: The comma is not part of a list. It's part of the _representation_ of a list.

Answer (score 0):

Your input is a numpy array:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([0.44346713, 0.70174108, 0.46043481, 0.82511308, 0.71445151])

print(a)
# [0.44346713 0.70174108 0.46043481 0.82511308 0.71445151]
```

Numpy has its built-in function of tolist():

```
print(a.tolist())
# [0.44346713, 0.70174108, 0.46043481, 0.82511308, 0.71445151]
```

Comment: This is a red herring: the goal of making the container indexable, selecting and extracting elements is possible without the list conversion.